# How to determine if current Request is a Task - GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using Google AppEngine with Java and the built in Task Queue.

Is there a way to determine wether the current call is a task that originated from the task queue?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are using push queues, you can check if any of the [Task Queue headers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/push/creating-handlers#writing_a_push_task_request_handler) are set.

The headers are:

```
X-AppEngine-QueueName
X-AppEngine-TaskName
X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount
X-AppEngine-TaskExecutionCount
X-AppEngine-TaskETA
```

Answer (score 3):

From the GAE docs at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/push/creating-handlers#writing_a_push_task_request_handler:

- X-AppEngine-QueueName, the name of the queue (possibly default)
- X-AppEngine-TaskName, the name of the task, or a system-generated unique ID if no name was specified
- X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount, the number of times this task has been retried; for the first attempt, this value is 0. This number includes attempts where the task failed due to a lack of available instances and never reached the execution phase.
- X-AppEngine-TaskExecutionCount, the number of times this task has previously failed during the execution phase. This number does not include failures due to a lack of available instances.
- X-AppEngine-TaskETA, the target execution time of the task, specified in microseconds since January 1st 1970.

Note that if you are really concerned about the origin of the request, you could secure the task URL to prevent the outside world from calling it.